# amchart5 how to add stocktoolbar

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, amcharts, amcharts5

I want to create a XY chart series chart similar to stock chart
now I have an issue to add stocktoolbar here.II'm getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: stockChart is not defined" please help me
here I wants to add date selector similar to stock chart and year rang
thanks in advance